# Selecting n random rows from a table for each unique customer

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if this is possible. Using the rand() function I can select random rows, however is it possible to select say 120 random rows and group by each customer, because I want 100 rows of data for each unique person. In addition is it possible to go one further level down and select 10 random rows for each month, for each customer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`RAND`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function inside an `ORDER BY` clause, then limit the amount of rows you need with the `LIMIT` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
ORDER BY RAND(45)
LIMIT 4
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mhoaTpjQ5mNCtEXDYsbVH4/0).

**Note 1**: If you want to have always the same customers, then [you can use a seed](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mhoaTpjQ5mNCtEXDYsbVH4/1) inside the `RAND` function.

**Note 2**: I wouldn't recommend this approach for large datasets, as it is quite expensive.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but can you help me understand how this chooses the same number of random entries for each unique customer?

Comment: Check the official RAND documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand. If you want to have always the same customers, then you can use a seed inside the RAND function.

Comment: Just read your second note. The dataset is huge. What alternatives do you suggest?

Comment: No alternatives as far as I know, but maybe there will be someone that knows some niche techniques for this task.